# delete words backwards

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I use Vim 7.4.576 on debian8.
I don't grasp the concept of deleting words backwards.

Here is some text. Cursor position is on "that" (the pipe symbol)

```
this is a new text on th|at line.
```

How can I delete the previous words, so as a result the sentence will look like this:

```
this is a line
```

Is this the best solution? <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>

......or is there a shorter way, so that i can skip the first <kbd>b</kbd>?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean `4b4dw` to get that result?

Answer (score 8):

You can use `b` as a motion for the delete instead of the `w` to delete backwards.

```
w4db
```

See [`:help {motion}`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#%7Bmotion%7D) for more info.

Comment: okay...b deletes the word before the cursor, and w also the word in the cursor. so you have to count correctly.

Comment: Instead of counting, you can also go with `w`, then `db` and repeat that with `.` (dot) operator (only `db` will be repeated). Maybe it's more keystrokes, but it may be faster than stopping and counting how many words to delete, plus if you want to delete 4 words, and later decide that one more needs to be deleted, then it's just one more `.` to press, and if you miscount, than it's just `u` to press, and only one word deletion will undone.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to insert mode and type `ctrl + wwww`. Not sure if it will work with gvim. Useful if you are already in insert mode